# How to partially revert a Git commit by a co-worker in VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, revert

I thought this would be simple, but it seems it's not. Or maybe it is.

A co-worker removed 10 large chunks from a file and committed the change. I pulled these changes.

Now I would like to revert, that is, re-include, 5 of these chunks. Without copy-and-pasting it myself.

What I tried:

- Open the file
- Choose the latest commit in the new [timeline view](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_44#_timeline-view).
- See the changes in diff view (`oldhash` <--> `newhash`): red blocks on the left, emptiness on the right, as expected.
- Select each block on the right, right-click, "Revert Selected Ranges". (Nothing happens.)

What I also tried:

- Go to Git: File History of the file
- Chose the commit before the offending commit
- Select file, choose Compare against workspace file
- See changes in diff view (Working tree): emptiness on the left, green blocks on the right, as expected.
- Select each block on the right, right-click, "Stage Selected Ranges" (Error message)

> "Git: cannot open git:/tmp/old-hash...
>   Detail: Unable to read file 'git:/tmp/old-hash...:"~"}' (EntryNotFound (FileSystemError))

How can I do what I want to do?

Comment: go to the commit before the offending commit, copy the file to /tmp, go to HEAD and use a merge tool to get the 5 blocks in

Comment: @rioV8 "copy the file to /tmp", "go to HEAD", "use a merge tool" - that is things I would do outside of VS Code, right? I thought VS Code would support this workflow somewhat natively.

Comment: How often will this happen in a normal workflow? Almost never. Why? Teams use reviews before committing/merging to the dev branch. So very unlikely the VSC team spend time adding a feature almost nobody will use.

Comment: @rioV8 not a bad point, thanks. Let me ask another question, then: these two actions that I tried above (Revert and Stage), what are they supposed to be doing if not what I expect them to? Even if my workflow will not be supported, I feel VS Code will need some polishing to remove actions from contexts where they are not working or not doing anything.

Comment: I just upgraded to VSC 1.44.2 and am unable to apply your steps. I can't select any of the "blocks" and I can't find the Revert and Stage context menu options. "Stage Selected Ranges" might be `Cherry Picking` during staging. Which extension are you using? (This is not default behavior or from GitLens). Disable all git related extensions and try again. Also the colors in the diff view are theme related, better to speak of -block and +block.

Comment: @rioV8 true, I had Git History installed, which gave me the "Git: File History" command in the second use case. I might file an issue with this extension then. The first use case is still possible, though: I can still cherry-pick in the diff view of any old commit in the timeline.

Comment: Cherry Pick is with the second case, I do the cherry-pick with the difference bar in the editor, if you click on a difference you get a peek window with the option to stage this difference and you then get an update of the differences compared to the index/stage.

Comment: @rioV8 I think the base issue for me is https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/48676. The problem is that actions such as "Stage Selected Ranges" appear in context where that is not useful - not only in diffs of earlier commits, but also non-version-control contexts.

Comment: These 2 commands are only available (or work) when you click on a file in the SCM tab, and only when you have a diff view that does not have an arrow in the file tab ( or two versions of the file). In only works in the `(Working tree)` and `(Index)` version of the diff view. They are editable. The diff views with arrow in tab are read only diffs but I can't find some feedback showing they are read only. But if the right file is the working tree version you have the commands but they do nothing. Is this a bug or should they be removed from the context menu

Comment: Looking at the picture I see you do it through the Timeline (need to watch the question better) and these commands in the context menu are wrong because we have a read only diff window (double arrow in tab name). If you have staged differences the tab is `(Index)` and the commands do nothing although `Unstage` should work and `Stage` should be removed/disabled because it already is staged. I don't what `Revert` should do here. You might file a bug report. Or amend the bug report 48676